# How to parse a list of comma separated name-value pairs into an array of hashtables

Tags: powershell, csv, key-value

I have a data file in the format:

```
"field1=value1","field2=data containing a ""double quote""","field3=data, with a comma"
"field1=value2","field4=more data"
```

Not every line's the same length, not every line has the same fields. I'm trying to parse it in to an array of hashtables, ultimately to convert it to XML as:

```
<file>
  <row>
    <field1>value1</field2>
    <field2>data containing a "double quote"</field2>
    <field3>data, with a comma</field3>
  </row>
  <row>
    <field1>value2</field1>
    <field4>more data</field4>
  </row>
</file>
```

I'm fairly sure I can output the XML from the hashtable array, and if I can't that'll be a separate question! But how do I parse it in in the first place, respecting the escape "" and commas within the field data?

Parsing using `ConvertFrom-StringData` needs the fields to be on separate lines, not comma separated, and splitting using `Import-Csv` doesn't break up the name-value pairs.

Comment: `"field1=value1","field2=data containing a ""double quote""","field3=data, with a comma" |ConvertFrom-StringData`

Comment: Now that's what I thought would happen, but it doesn't seem to work when I read the file in using `foreach ($line in <filename>) { $line | ConvertFrom-StringData }`

Comment: (To clarify, I actually did `foreach ($line in Get-Content <filename>)`, forgot that bit.

Comment: Ok, after a little investigation, entering the string directly like that actually passes an array to ConvertFrom-StringData; each line of the file is just a string.

Comment: And no, I can't use -split ",", that won't handle the comma in the data correctly.

Answer (score 1):

```
$Data = # Get-Content .\Data.txt
'"field1=value1","field2=data containing a ""double quote""","field3=data, with a comma"',
'"field1=value2","field4=more data"'
    
$Xml = [System.Xml.XmlDocument]::new()
$File = $Xml.AppendChild($Xml.CreateElement('file'))
foreach ($Line in $Data) {
    $Row = $File.AppendChild($Xml.CreateElement('row'))
    $Items = ($Line |ConvertFrom-Csv -Header (0..9)).PSObject.Properties.Value.Where{$_}
    foreach ($Item in $Items) {
        $Name, $Value = $Item.Split('=', 2)
        $Field = $Row.AppendChild($Xml.CreateElement($Name))
        $Field.InnerText = $Value
    }
}
$Xml.outerxml
```

```
<file><row><field1>value1</field1><field2>data containing a "double quote"</field2><field3>data, with a comma</field3></row><row><field1>value2</field1><field4>more data</field4></row></file>
```